# Line break before and after <ul> not equal

Tags: html, css

I have a `<br>` before and after an unordered list.  The spacing of the `<br>`'s don't seem to be equal though.  Please see https://jsfiddle.net/052620dm/ (the second `<br>` is bigger than the first).  It looks like adding a `br` before the `ul` doesn't do anything.  Changing the unordered list to another `display` fixes the issue but obviously makes it no longer an unordered list.  Any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Don't use `<br>` for layouting, use CSS.

To your problem: The first `<br>` breaks the text to a new line. This means, that there is no spacing between the 'hi' and the `<ul>`, because the `<ul>` starts directly at the new line. The `<ul>` is a block element and automatically pushes the text after to a new line. Then, the 2nd `<br>` comes and breaks to a new line again. This creates the larger spacing.

```
hi
<br>           // linebreak
<ul>           // <ul> starts directly at this new line
<li>test</li>
</ul>          // <ul> is a block element and pushes the element after to a newline
<br>           // another new line is added (there comes your empty space from)
hi
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would want to use a br before and after the list. Why not just set a margin?

If you need to use the br tags, wrap your text in p tags and you'll get the same spacing before and after the list.